# Render react component after filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have component with articles:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ArticleList from "../ArticlesListApp";

class Articles extends Component {
  render() {
    const { articleList } = this.props;
    return (
      <ArticleList list={articleList} />
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    articleList: state.articles
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Articles);
```

Articles is array with objects, and I have a button for filters by name.

I have reducer for this action:

```
import { articles } from '../Content/Content';

export default (articleList = articles, action) => {

  switch(action.type) {
    case 'FILTERS-NAME' : {
      console.log(articleList);
      return articleList.sort(filtersArea);

    }
    default :
      return articleList;
  }
}


function filtersArea(a, b) {
  if (a.name < b.name)
    return -1;
  if (a.name > b.name)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

And now, if I print in console my array after click on filter btn, I get a new sorted array.
But it not rendering.

Where I have wrong?

Comment: can you post the ArticlesList component?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mutate the state object on the reducer. Here it is from the redux [docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers):

> Note that:
>
> We don't mutate the state. We create a copy with Object.assign().
>   Object.assign(state, { visibilityFilter: action.filter }) is also
>   wrong: it will mutate the first argument. You must supply an empty
>   object as the first parameter. You can also enable the object spread
>   operator proposal to write { ...state, ...newState } instead.

So you should be doing something like:

```
 case 'FILTERS-NAME' : {
  let sortedList = [...articleList];
  return sortedList.sort(filtersArea);
}
```